Steampunk book about a female lead who lives on an island and works in a volcano
I found the book on iBooks in 2017 or 2018. Its a steampunk series with a female lead character. I only read the first book in the series.
This book is steampunk and starts with the female character living on a beautiful island. The island is arts focused. They prioritize singing, painting, sculpting etc. Her siblings are artistic along with her mom and sister being incredibly beautiful in her opinion in comparison to herself. She does not have any artistic abilities or passions like everyone else.
Instead the main character starts off working (I think) in a volcano that is used for the steam needed for the traveling steampunk balloons that visit the island for trading. She is far more interested in traveling off her island. Even though it is known to be far more dangerous anywhere else in the world.
She does happen to leave and starts as a wrench hand helping keep the balloon afloat as the balloon travels to the next destination.

The inversion premise "Everybody is so free-spirited and artistic, I hate it here. I want to go and do manual labor." sounds kinda interesting, especially for a steampunk book.

Could this be Free-Wrench by Joseph Lallo? It's the first in a five book steampunk series.
The main character is called Nita (Amanita) who works in the steamworks on a chain of volcanic islands called Caldera. From the cover blurb:

The islands of Caldera are a shining jewel in a rather bleak world. A
terrible calamity in the past had blanketed much of the world with a
toxic "fug." Those who survived were forced to take to the mountains
and the skies in wondrous airships. Life has since been a struggle,
with only the most ruthless and crafty able to survive. To spare
themselves the same fate, the Calderans erected a battery of guns to
fend off the airships of the mainland. They isolated themselves from
the madness of the world, choosing instead to focus on the pursuits of
art and creativity. Few believe the technologically advanced but
socially barbarous outsiders have anything to offer. Amanita Graus,
though, is hoping that they do.

She joins the crew of an airship called "The Wind Breaker" as part of:

an eccentric crew of smugglers; the gruff Cap’n Mack, the simple but
enthusiastic Lil and Coop, the arrogant marksman Gunner, the surly
surgeon Butch, and the irritable mascot Wink.

